# In Node how to merge an array of objects into a new array where each object name has it's values in an array of strings?

Tags: node.js, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects that looks like:

```
const arr = [
    {
        "name": "Day",
        "value": "Monday"
    },
    {
        "name": "Month",
        "value": "November"
    },
    {
        "name": "Day",
        "value": "Monday"
    },
    {
        "name": "Month",
        "value": "December"
    },
    {
        "name": "Day",
        "value": "Friday"
    },
    {
        "name": "Month",
        "value": "November"
    },
    {
        "name": "Day",
        "value": "Friday"
    },
    {
        "name": "Month",
        "value": "December"
    }
]
```

but I'm needing to modify my array of objects to:

```
const final = [
    {
        "name": "Day",
        "values": [
            "Monday",
            "Friday"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Month",
        "values": [
            "November",
            "December"
        ]
    }
]
```

I can filter out the duplicates with:

```
const filtered = arr.filter(
    (v, i, a) =>
      a.findIndex(v2 => v?.name === v2?.name && v?.value === v2?.value) === i
  );
```

but I'm stuck on the approach on an efficient way to do this without [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) or [underscore](https://underscorejs.org/) and I've tried using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) but my implementation isn't working:

```
const test = filtered.map(({ name, value }) =>
    Object.assign({ name, value: [] }, (name, value))
  );
console.log(test)
```

Thought I had seen this asked before and tested answers from:

- [How to merge an array with an object where values are arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33811456/how-to-merge-an-array-with-an-object-where-values-are-arrays)
- [How to merge two array of objects by key AND keep unique keys in a single array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64624254/how-to-merge-two-array-of-objects-by-key-and-keep-unique-keys-in-a-single-array)
- [From array of Object , get array of only matched key value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66221321/from-array-of-object-get-array-of-only-matched-key-value)
- [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)
- [Merge multiple objects inside the same array into one object [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27538349/merge-multiple-objects-inside-the-same-array-into-one-object)

In an array of objects and can I combine the objects with the same name but have the value in an array of strings?

Comment: After you've removed your duplicates, you probably want to have a look at `reduce` rather than `map`, where you build up a new array as you iterate over each element. Although given what your final data looks like, I'm not sure an array is the right choice. Having a final _object_ with `days` and `months` keys that each point to an array of strings would be far easier to use in downstream code.

Comment: the issue is the final result in the question *is* what's expected downstream or I'd do the approach you referred.

Comment: Then `reduce` will get you there, and `Set` will help remove the need to filter anything.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with a start value that has your days and moths elements preallocated, using a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to automatically ignore duplicates, and then after you've reduced everything, converting that set into an array:

```js
const arr = [{
    name: "Day",
    value: "Monday",
  },{
    name: "Month",
    value: "November",
  },{
    name: "Day",
    value: "Monday",
  },{
    name: "Month",
    value: "December",
  },{
    name: "Day",
    value: "Friday",
  },{
    name: "Month",
    value: "November",
  },{
    name: "Day",
    value: "Friday",
  },{
    name: "Month",
    value: "December",
}];

// reduce the data to the form you need:
const final = arr.reduce(
  (resultSoFar, {name, value}) => {
    // find the "bin" to add this value to:
    let bin = resultSoFar.find((e) => e.name === name);
    // or make a new bin if there isn't one:
    if (!bin) resultSoFar.push(bin = { name, values: new Set() });
    // then add our value, and return the new result so far.
    bin.values.add(value);
    return resultSoFar;
  },
  // and start with `resultSoFar` being an empty array:
  []
);

// as last step, convert the sets into plain arrays:
final.forEach(e => e.values = [...e.values]);

// what did we get?
console.log(final);
```

Comment: that works and interesting approach with `reduce` going to study this and learn more about it. Think Im somewhat confused on what's `resultSoFar`.

Comment: Also could the `new Set` be modified to not have to convert down the pipe in the `forEach` if I'm understanding the approach correctly? Is there a reason for the implementation of the `new Set()` compared to other approaches?

Comment: ah I see from the recent comment that `new Set` removes the need for filtering.

Comment: You said that the form you showed for your `const final` was specifically what you needed, so the forEach just hard-converts the `Set` to an `Array`, since Sets don't "have" indices, and don't support bracket notation.

Comment: As for `resultSoFar`, that's the key aspect of `reduce`: it starts with whatever you specified as second argument of your reduce call, and at each iteration step your return value becomes the next iteration step's `resultSoFar`, with the last iteration step's return being what `reduce` itself returns.